# In REST API call what should we return in case of empty result

Tags: rest, api, httpresponse

I am having 2 services-
1. Client Service
2. Feature Service

Client Service asks feature service for feature corresponding to a client. If in the database no feature found for a client should what should we return?
1. 404 no resource found
2. 204 Success - No content
3. 200 Success - {features:[]} // Empty list

Comment: Preamble: This is a convention, there is no REST police checking your responses. My approach would be 404 if you're asking for a concrete feature ("GET feature/1") or 200 with an empty list if you're asking for all features ("GET feature") if the response contains additional information, 204 no content otherwise.

Comment: This boils down to design choice. No 1 should be taken if it is considered a failure when no features are available if not then options 2 and 3 are primarily preferable. In reagards to No. 3 the media-type should define what an empty result set should look like. As REST requires proper cache handling, all 3 options are cacheable by default, so there isn't much of a difference actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, I have always returned a 200 with an empty list.  The fact that the list is empty tells the consumer that, although nothing went wrong with the request, there are no resources associated with it.

The 204 is a fair compromise between the 200 and the 404 but I think that it adds minimal value.

I would personally shy away from throwing a 404 on an endpoint that returns a list since it is expected that there will be situations where the list is empty (that is potentially too broad of a statement).  If the request was failing because of the resource associated with the list then I would definitely consider the 404 valid (let's say you had a user with a list of hats and the request for the hats was for a NOT FOUND user).

Answer (score 0):

HTTP response should be 200, Just show "empty" result in TAG

Answer (score 0):

You can return in two ways. 404 is not valid if no content is present.

```
a) 204 No Content
Explaination: The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation.


b) Return 200 and with empty body {};
```

You can find more at w3 https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: [RFC2616 is dead](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead) - stated by one of the minds behind RFC7230-35